# SQL Debugging for a Visual Basic MS access OLEDB application

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table "Result" that has 8 columns with the 1st column set to auto-numbering. I am trying to run an `INSERT` statement by omitting column 1 as follows, however I get an error message:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

```
Dim insertSql = "INSERT INTO [Result] (MemberNo, MemberName, MemberSurname, EventTitle, FinishTimeMin, FinishTimeSec, Position) VALUES ('" & resultC.MemberNo & "','" & resultC.MemberName & "','" & resultC.MemberSurname & "','" & resultC.EventTitle & "','" & resultC.FinishMin & "','" & resultC.FinishSec & "','" & resultC.Position & "')"
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of `insertSql`. There seems to be something in one of your variables which is messing up the query. (Probably a single quote)

Answer (score 0):

At least Time is probably numeric (and Position too?), thus:

```
... "'," & resultC.FinishMin & "," & resultC.FinishSec & ",'" ...
```